# Views field that links to fragment URL of comment on /node/ instead of /comment/

Tags: views, 8, uri, comments

With Views, I want to output a list that links to each comment of the current node. But instead of linking to

```
/comment/42#comment-42
```

I want to link to

```
/node/23#comment-42
```

I tried these fields, but they all link to the URL in the `/comment/` space:

- Comment: Title (Formatter: Plain text)

  ```
  /comment/42
  ```
- Comment: Title (Formatter: Comment Permalink)

  ```
  /comment/42#comment-42
  ```
- Comment: Link to Comment

  ```
  /comment/42
  ```

**Is there a way to output anchors in the `/node/` space?** The solution doesn’t need to support comment pagination (a node will never reach the limit).

Answer (score 1):

An ugly workaround (which will **not** work for paginated comments):

1. Add the field "**Content: Link to Content**"

   1. Use the relationship "Content" (should be default when creating a comments view)
   2. Enable "Exclude from display"
   3. Enable "Output the URL as text"
2. Add the field "**Comment: Comment ID**"

   1. Set "Formatter" to "Unformatted"
   2. Enable "Exclude from display"
3. Add the field "**Comment: Title**"

   1. Set "Formatter" to "Plain text"
   2. Disable "Link to the Comment"
   3. Enable "Output this field as a custom link" (under "Rewrite results")
   4. Link path: `{{ view_node }}#comment-{{ cid }}`
      (field names might differ, use what’s listed under "Replacement patterns")